# How do I load an object object from a Future class into another object/class?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have two Futures which load a String from a JSON File for me. My Goal is to have a class Data within which, I can hold different objects (for example Feed). What I don't understand right now, is how I write a class data which can hold the object feed, as well as, load the feed object from the Future.

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:freeletics_insights/feed.dart';


Future<String> _loadFeedAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/userfeed1.json');
}

Future<Feed> loadFeed() async {
  String jsonFeed = await _loadFeedAsset();
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonFeed);
  Feed feed = new Feed.fromJson(jsonResponse);
  //print(feed.feedEntries.length);
  return feed;
}


class Data {
  Feed feed;

  Data.loadData(){
    this.feed = loadFeed();
  }
}

void main{
  var data = Data.loadData();
  print(data.feed.feedEntries.length);
}
```

I alway get an error that the type 
    FutureFeed 
cannot be assigned to a type Feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that used to slip me up a bit when I first started using Dart and Flutter. Your `loadFeed()` method returns a type of `Future<Feed>` but your `Data` classes member `feed` is of type `Feed`, which are two different types. What you want to do is "unwrap" the `Future<Feed>` returned from your `loadFeed()` method in order to access the `Feed` object.

You "unwrap" `Future` objects using the `async/await` syntax.

What it might look like you can do is:

```
class Data {
  Feed feed;

  Data.loadData() async {
    this.feed = await loadFeed();
  }
}
```

... but you `loadData()` is a constructor of `Data` and you can't have constructor methods marked as `async`. You can however mark you `main()` method as `async` to use `async/await` syntax to unwrap your `Future<Feed>`.

The only thing I've changed in your code is added your `feed` member of `Data` to the constructor and adapted your `main()` method to asyncronously load your feed and pass the result into the constructor of  your `Data` object.

```
Future<String> _loadFeedAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/userfeed1.json');
}

Future<Feed> loadFeed() async {
  String jsonFeed = await _loadFeedAsset();
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonFeed);
  Feed feed = new Feed.fromJson(jsonResponse);
  //print(feed.feedEntries.length);
  return feed;
}


class Data {
  Feed feed;

  Data(this.feed);
}

void main async {
  var feed = await loadFeed();
  var data = Data(feed);
  print(data.feed.feedEntries.length);
}
```